# Angular 2 - ngOnDestroy is not triggered

Tags: javascript, angular

demo http://plnkr.co/edit/7uoVecfa62i8No8GtQHI?p=preview

When I hide the first section with nested components using *ngIf, ngOnDestroy of every nested component is triggered.

```
<div *ngIf="!ff2">
    <my-component
    ></my-component>
    <my-component
    ></my-component>
    <my-component
    ></my-component>
    <my-component
    ></my-component>
    <my-component
    ></my-component>
  </div>
```

Output in console is:

```
    init
    init
    init
    init
    init
    destroy
    destroy
    destroy
    destroy
    destroy
```

But when I hide the second section where subcomponents are duplicated by *ngFor, not every ngOnDestroy is triggered.

```
 <div *ngIf="!ff">
        <my-component
          *ngFor="#i of [1,2,3,4,5,6]"
        ></my-component>
      </div>
```

Output in console is:

```
(6) init
(3) destroy
```

Do you have any idea if I do something wrong, or there is an issue in angular2? Thanks.

Comment: in angular beta 9 it works as I expected so they have a bug

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q8tLJKlpF6wEVcMWfxH1?p=preview

Comment: Bug report https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8458

Answer (score 1):

Try below mentioned code. it should work,

```
<button type="button" (click)="ff = !ff">toggle</button>
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="[1,2,3,4,5,6]">
  <my-component *ngIf="!ff"></my-component>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In [OP’s own words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012854/angular-2-ngondestroy-is-not-triggered/43672544#comment61590601_37012854):

> in angular beta 9 it works as I expected so they have a bug

Confirmed by OP’s own [bug report](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8458) (closed).